# How to compile the Javascript code in Karate framework

Tags: javascript, cucumber, karate

I've the JSON as below:

```
 {
  "id" : 6759,
  "type" : "JAVASCRIPT",
  "code" : "var result = request.getBody().tostring.indexOf('locate') || request.getBody().tostring.indexOf('find')",
  "description" : "This filters checks synonym of search word"
}
```

In above JSON, **code** attribute is mapped with certain javascript.

I've to validate the value of code attribute.

The validation of value of code attribute should return true, if value of code attribute has no any compilation error.

The validation of value of code attribute should return false, if value of code attribute has compilation error using.

How should make possible to compile the javascript ( i.e. value of **code** attribute) as part of validation in Intuite/karate testing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile JS but you can `eval` it. Take the help of someone near you who knows JavaScript (and who can *actually read* the documentation) if you have trouble understanding the below.

```
* def script = "request.getBody().tostring.indexOf('locate') || request.getBody().tostring.indexOf('find')"
* def code = true
* eval try { karate.eval(script) } catch (e) { karate.set('code', false) }
* print code
* def response =
"""
{
  "id" : 6759,
  "type" : "JAVASCRIPT",
  "code" : "#(code)",
  "description" : "This filters checks synonym of search word"
}
"""
```